# Close FancyBox form after Symfony validation

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, fancybox

How to close a FancyBox containing a Symfony form after the form has been submitted ? I don't want to close the fancybox after the button is immediately clicked since the form can raise errors.

One solution seems to use **two Symfony functions** (with two distinct routes) in the controller :

- One for **rendering the form**
- One for **returning a "json" response** after form is submitted.

In this way, the response contains the errors. Then, in Ajax function, according to the errors, the FancyBox can be closed.

I saw **two disavantages** at this solution :

1. Does the form will make two calls on each submit ? Do we break the Symfony logic ?
2. Does returning a json response require displaying errors by hand in the form ?

Is it the best way to perform ?

Bellow is the structure of the two functions in the Controller :

```
     /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/rendering_form", name="renderingForm")
     */
     public function renderingForm(Request $request){
          // ... Data request for rendering

          // Building form for rendering
          $form = $this->createMyForm()->getForm();

          $form->handleRequest($request);

          if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
              return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
          }

          return $this->render('@Map/Book/book.html.twig', 
                              array(  // data for rendering ,
                                      "form" => $form->createView()
                               ));
```

```php
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/rendering_form/validation", name="validationRenderingForm")
     */
    public function validationRenderingForm(Request $request){
        $form = $this->createMyForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $errors = $this->getDataErrorCustom($data);

            if ($errors){
                 $response = ['status' => 'fail',
                              'errors' => $errors ];
            }else{
                 $response = ['status' => 'success'];
            }
        }else {
            $response = ["status" => 'fail',
                         "errors" => $form->getErrors()];
        }

        $reponse = new Response(json_encode($reponse));
        $reponse->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $reponse;
    }
```

Comment: You can simplify this logic by having one action for both cases. In your `renderingForm`-action you can check if the request was submitted via FancyBox by calling `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` (true means it's js, false means it's a regular form submit, e.g. when js is disabled). Depending on the value you can either return a JsonResponse or just render the form and return a typical Response with html.

Comment: Yes! `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` do the trick ! I still have problems with the form but I don't think it's the same reason. I opened a new [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991253/add-choicetype-options-in-symfony-form-on-non-entity-class)

Answer (score 0):

fancybox provides a handy `beforeClose` callback, you can use it to stop closing the modal, simply return `false`. So, if you choose to use ajax to submit and validate your form, you can display loading icon while waiting for reponse (use `hideLoading` for hiding):

`$.fancybox.getInstance().showLoading( $.fancybox.getInstance().current );`

and close on success:

`$.fancybox.getInstance().close()`

And for the php part I would suggest to follow dbrumann comment.