# Add ChoiceType options in Symfony form on Non Entity Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

I have a Symfony form submitted by Ajax request. This form contains 2 fields : a date (datepicker) and a number of days (a choiceType). I can't initialize the number of days when the form is built since it relies on the date selected. Using Javascript, I update the options in select-picker. That works very well. Typically, an option looks like this : `<option value="1">1 jours<\option>`.

Now, when the form is submitted, I need to add those fields in the choiceType.

I used isXmlHttpRequest method because **the form is submitted with an Ajax request**, waiting for an answer. **If the form is valid, I need to inform the Ajax call** (I dont want to render another template). 
I do the following in the Controller:

```php
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/ajout_favoris", name="ajoutFavoris")
     */
    public function ajoutFavoris(Request $request){

        $form = $this->creerFormulaire()->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
            if ($form->isValid() ) {
                // actions ...

                $reponse = ['statut' => 'success'];

            }else {
                $reponse = ['statut' => 'form-invalid'];
            }
            $reponse = new Response(json_encode($reponse));
            $reponse->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return $reponse;
        }

        return $this->render('@Carte/Reservation/reservation.html.twig', array(
            "form" => $form->createView() ));
```

Here is how I build the form :

```php
    public function creerFormulaire(){
        $formulaire = $this->createFormBuilder()

            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $data = $event->getData();
                $optionList = $this->getValidChoicesForNbJours($data["nbJours"]);
                $form->add('nbJours', 'choice', array(
                    'attr' => [ 'placeholder' => 'nombre de jours',
                        'class' => 'selectpicker',
                        ],
                    'choices' => $optionsList,
                ));
            })
            ->add('dateDebut', DateTimeType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'label' => 'Date début',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => ['class' => 'datepicker input-date',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'placeholder' => 'JJ/MM/AAAA',
                    'readonly' => true,
                    'required' => true,]
            ])
            ->add('nbJours', 'choice', [
                'label' => 'Nombre de jours',
                'choices' => [],
                'attr' => [ 'placeholder' => 'nombre de jours',
                    'class' => 'selectpicker',
                    'title' => 'Nombre de jours',
                    'readonly' => true,
                    'required' => false,]

            ])
            ->add('ajoutFavoris', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Ajouter aux favoris',
                'attr' => [ 'class' => 'btn btn-primary reserver' ]
            ]);
        return $formulaire;
    }
```

And here how I fill the options :

```php
public function getValidChoicesForNbJours($range){
        $liste = [];
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $range; $i++){
            $liste[$i.' jours'] = strval($i);
        }
        return $liste;
    }
```

and here is the ajax call :

```
path_to_add_fav = ...
idPlan = ...
$("#form_ajoutFavoris").click(function (e) {
    let dateDebut = document.getElementById('form_dateDebut').value;
    let nbJours = document.getElementById('form_nbJours').value;

    if (dateDebut && nombreJours){
        let data = {
            poste_id: idPoste,
            plan_id: idPlan,
            nbJours: nbJours ,
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: path_to_add_fav,
            type: "post",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.statut);
                if (data.statut === "success") {
                    window.parent.$.fancybox.close();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

There is no error in Chrome console. At the fisrt submit, it always display `form-invalid`, on the following, sometimes display `form-invalid`, sometines nothing...

I read a lot of "similar post" but haven't been able the achieve mine. This post is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984958/close-fancybox-form-after-symfony-validation) but the question is now different.

Thank you for reading !

> EDIT : Add HTML

```html
{{ form_start(form) }}
                <div class="card-deck maxheight">
                    {% include '@Carte/Carte/poste_card.html.twig' with {'poste':poste, 'connected':connected, 'showbtn':false } %}

                    <div class="card card-form" id="card-reserv">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {{ form_errors(form) }}

                            <div id="warning-pecheurs" class="alert alert-warning padding alert-dismissible"
                                 role="alert">
                                <button type="button" class="close float-right" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                                warning message
                            </div>

                            <table id="table" class="largeur">
                                <colgroup>
                                    <col span="1" class="col1">
                                    <col span="1" class="col2">
                                </colgroup>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                {{ form_label(form.dateDebut) }}
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="date">
                                            {{ form_widget(form.dateDebut) }}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            {{ form_errors(form.dateDebut) }}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                {{ form_label(form.nbJours) }}
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ form_widget(form.nbJours) }}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            {{ form_errors(form.nbJours) }}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin0">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
                            onclick="window.parent.$.fancybox.close()" value="CloseFB">
                        Annuler
                    </button>
                    {{ form_widget(form.ajoutFavoris) }}
                </div>

                {{ form_end(form) }}
```

And here how I populate the select-picker in JS:

```
let new_options = "";
for (i = 0; i < nbOptions; i++, j++)
        new_options += "<option value=" + j + ">" + j + " jours</option>";
$("#form_nbJours").html(new_options).selectpicker('refresh');
```

> EDIT : Solution
>   **The Ajax method call is the guilty !** With this call, it works perfectly !

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    console.log("ok");
    e.preventDefault();
    let formSerialize = $(this).serialize();

    $.post(path_to_add_fav, formSerialize, function(response) {
        console.log(response.statut);
        if (response.statut === "success") {
            console.log("Réponse correcte !");
            window.parent.$.fancybox.close();
        }
    }, 'JSON');
}
```

Comment: Please, provide some html of how your form is rendered. It's very likely that the reason is the missing form-token that is not sent along with the data. Do you have disabled CSRF? Have you already tried to send the `token`-field as well?

Comment: I don't touch CSRF protection. Symfony form automatically add an hidden input for the token (that we can wee in the page in browser if analyzed). Adding the token value in data like this `data = {CSRF : document.getElementById('form__token').value}` or adding this [method](https://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/static-118.html?blogid=118) change nothing.

Comment: Right! Have you also tried this `data = { _token : document.getElementById('form__token').value}`. Assuming that this hidden form-field is called `_token`

Answer (score 0):

you can disable form validation by calling  `$builder->get('nbJours')->resetViewTransformers();` after you have added the field